# Display Entries by URL Title to a Category?

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Let's say I have the following page.

www.mysite.com/about/video/

I have the following links on it.

www.mysite.com/about/video/examples

www.mysite.com/about/video/tutorials

I also have a channel where the user can add a category of either examples or tutorials as the category name which is matched to the URL. Is there a way to display a list of entries that match the third segment of the url string to a category assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) and then write channel entry tag like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL_NAME" category="{last_segment_category_id}"}
#####
#####
#####
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your URLs set in stone?  EE can return entries based on category natively/dynamically - but it has to be a proper EE category URL: mysite.com/about/video/category/examples.  A standard channel:entries tag at that URL would return entries in that category with no addons or special code needed.